# React - add props to a component represented by an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to add props to a component represented by an object?
I would like to add those props only once, inside the map function, if possible.

```
children: [
    {
      id: '1',
      isActive: false,
      label: 'Home',
      component: <ReportsIcon height={30} width={30} />,
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      isActive: true,
      label: 'Dashboard',
      component: <SettingsIcon height={30} width={30} />,
    },
  ].map((item) => (
    <MenuLink key={item.id} isActive={false} label={item.label}>
      <a href={`#`}>
        {item.component // ADD PROPS HERE //}
        {item.label}
      </a>
    </MenuLink>
  )),
```

Comment: Why not use `component: (props) => ..` or  `component: SettingsIcon`?

Comment: I would like to add additional props to each component dynamically (where I wrote // ADD PROPS HERE //

Comment: @sir-haver read the comment once again

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't explain myself well enough, I wouldn't want to receive props in each component in the array, I would like to set it only once inside the map function if possible, to not repeat the code in each component in the array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options proposed by [Njuguna Mureithi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1418750/njuguna-mureithi)
1.

```
children: [
    {
      id: '1',
      isActive: false,
      label: 'Home',
      component: props => <ReportsIcon height={30} width={30} {...props} />,
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      isActive: true,
      label: 'Dashboard',
      component: props => <SettingsIcon height={30} width={30} {...props} />,
    },
  ].map((item) => (
    <MenuLink key={item.id} isActive={false} label={item.label}>
      <a href={`#`}>
        {item.component({ prop: 123 })}
        {item.label}
      </a>
    </MenuLink>
  )),
```

2. 

```
children: [
    {
      id: '1',
      isActive: false,
      label: 'Home',
      component: ReportsIcon,
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      isActive: true,
      label: 'Dashboard',
      component: SettingsIcon,
    },
  ].map((item) => (
    <MenuLink key={item.id} isActive={false} label={item.label}>
      <a href={`#`}>
        <item.component height={30} width={30} prop={123} />
        {item.label}
      </a>
    </MenuLink>
  )),
```

Comment: Ohh I get it, what I was missing is the syntax  {item.component({ prop: 123 })}, thanks a lot to both of you!